# Parse Audio with Slider

Tags: swift, parse-platform, avaudioplayer, avplayer, uislider

How do you add an audio file from parse to an `AVAudioPlayer` and not an `AVPlayer`? I want to be able to pause, play, stop, replay, and use a slider to control audio playback. I tried this:

My attempt:

```
var query = PFQuery(className:"Song1")
query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId("YSuNRfKq3n") {
    (object : PFObject?, error : NSError?) -> Void in
        if let AudioFileURLTemp = object?.objectForKey("SongFile")?.url {
            AudioPlayer = AVPlayer(URL: NSURL(string: AudioFileURLTemp!))
            AudioPlayer.play()
        }
    )
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "it doesn't work?"  What error are you getting?

Comment: I believe for Streaming Audio from parse you can only use AVPlayer but it says: Use of unresolved identifier 'AudioFileURLTemp'

Comment: That error means that your class can't find a variable named `AudioFileURLTemp`.  Are you sure you have a variable named that?  Where is the audio file that you want to play?

Comment: This is what Im doing and it plays the background audio file from Parse: var query = PFQuery(className:"Song1")
        query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId("YSuNRfKq3n") {
            (object : PFObject?, error : NSError?) -> Void in
            
            
            if let AudioFileURLTemp = object?.objectForKey("SongFile")?.url{
                
                AudioPlayer = AVPlayer(URL: NSURL(string: AudioFileURLTemp!))
                AudioPlayer.play()

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var query = PFQuery(className:"Song1")
query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId("objectId") {
    (object : PFObject?, error : NSError?) -> Void in
        if let AudioFileURLTemp = object?.objectForKey("SongFile")?.url {
            AudioPlayer = AVPlayer(URL: NSURL(string: AudioFileURLTemp!))
            AudioPlayer.play()
        }
    )
}
```

Comment: Does not work, all I want to do is be able to use pause, play, stop, replay, and use a slider to control audio playback with an audio file from parse, but it seems that it's harder than I thought.

Answer (score 0):

class ViewController: UIViewController, AVAudioPlayerDelegate, AVAudioRecorderDelegate {

```
var goAudio = AVPlayer()
var show = AVAudioPlayer()

var soundData : NSData!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    streamShow()
}

@IBAction func playShow(sender: UIButton) {
    self.show.prepareToPlay()
    self.show.volume = 1.0
    self.show.delegate = self
    self.show.play()
}

func streamShow(){
    var query = PFQuery(className:"sveglia")
    query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId("hQHeNCqccH") {
        (object : PFObject?, error : NSError?) -> Void in
        if let AudioFileURLTemp = object?.objectForKey("audio")?.url {

            self.goAudio = AVPlayer(URL: NSURL(string: AudioFileURLTemp!))

            let fileURL = NSURL(string: AudioFileURLTemp!)
            var error: NSError?
            let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: fileURL!)
            self.show = AVAudioPlayer(data: data, error: &error)

        }
    }
}
```

}